# Date comparison loop second time onwards giving NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to compare dates, first working fine, second time onwards it `(durationTime = difference between dates)` throws NaN,

Getting problem here

```
var durationTime = ((new Date(endDateVal[2],endDateVal[1],endDateVal[0],endDateVal[3],endDateVal[4],endDateVal[5])) -(new Date(startDateVal[2],startDateVal[1],startDateVal[0],startDateVal[3],startDateVal[4],startDateVal[5])) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

here is my code, please help me on this

```
var rowlength = $("#totalLostProductGrid tbody tr ").length;

for(var i=1;i<=rowlength;i++){


    var startDateVal = $("#lpostartDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/);
    var endDateVal= $("#lpoendDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/);
    var lostProductValue = $("#lostProductionStartToEnd_"+i).val();
    var realEndDateVal = $("#eEndTime").val().split(/-|\s|:/);

    var FLNominalvalue = $("#idNominalPower").text();
    var idEstimatedLostProdVal = $("#idEstimatedLostProd").val();


    var durationTime = ((new Date(endDateVal[2],endDateVal[1],endDateVal[0],endDateVal[3],endDateVal[4],endDateVal[5])) -(new Date(startDateVal[2],startDateVal[1],startDateVal[0],startDateVal[3],startDateVal[4],startDateVal[5])) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

    var actualVal = durationTime * lostProductValue;

    alert(actualVal);

    if(actualVal  < FLNominalvalue){
        alert("success");

    }else{
        alert("invalid case");

        }

}
```

Comment: So are you sure that elements are being returned? Sort of hard to debug without the html. `console.log( $("#lpostartDate_"+i).val(), $("#lpoendDate_"+i).val(), $("#lostProductionStartToEnd_"+i).val(), $("#eEndTime").val());`

Comment: it will be easy to debug if you make a fiddle of your code